# Hashtable implementation for C

Tags: c, hashtable, mpi

what is a good hashtable implementation for C? I need to use it with mpicc compiler. Delete function is not necessary.

Comment: None, actually. Moreover the hashtable would be immutable.

Comment: Immutable in the sense 'once created and not changed later'.

Comment: Is the data known at compile time? Then you could use a perfect hash generator as Remo.D suggested.

Comment: Yes, the data is nkown at compile time.

Answer (score 4):

The one in [glib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html) is very nice. Not sure if it's too large and/or possible to isolate from the rest of glib, though.

Failing that, [Pearson hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_hashing) seems to be a good starting point for implementing your own (it's a hash function optimized for machines with 8-bit registers).

Comment: glib is nice but it's so big that I wouldn't suggest to include it in your project just for that. If you also need all the other features glib has, though, I agree that would be the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

If the keys are all known in advance, you may use a [perfect hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) generator avoid the space overhead that is implicit in hash tables.

If, on the other hand, you really need a full hash table, I would suggest a variation of [Cuckoo Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing) (e.g. the d-ary version).

I've used with satisfaction a simplified version of the [Hopscotch Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopscotch_hashing) that works rather well even at higher load factors.